# WildCard Id Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have different applications to test on device and found that using wildcardId we dont have to create multiple bundleIdentifiers. So created a single wildcard Id `com.testing.*`
But when I run applications with this Identifier one application replaces by another

How can I manage multiple apps with single Id ?

Any suggestions/ideas would be helpful

Comment: Questions:

1. For your app ID, have you set up multiple provisioning profiles?
2. Is this a regular or enterprise account?

Comment: set differ app id like com.testing.a,com.testing.b ,com.testing.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Wildcard Id you can easily Install multiple apps without replacing each other.

You just need use it like this:

- Let say you are using wildcard Id in firstApp than add bundle Identifier with named "com.testing.firstApp" (Considered com.testing.* as wildcard Id)
- Now if you want install second App than add bundle Identifier with named "com.testing.secondApp"
- In short you just need to add App name in place of * at last.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Many thanks Mack. Its working. But I have a small question do we  really need to create many provisioning profiles with wildcardId? Lets say different development and distribution certificates for each app with same wildcard ID as per @dokun1 comments above. I mean its really working without that too

Comment: No need, as you created wildcard you can use it

Answer (score 0):

By using Wildcard Id you can easily Install multiple apps without replacing each other.

First create wildcard profile id like (com.mydomainname.*)

Then Goto "Build Settings" - Search "Build Identifier" - then change identifier as below,
**com.myDomainName.$(PRODUCT_NAME)**

by using above line of statement Xcode automatically generate your bundle identifier based on your product name. 
If you change your product name, Xcode will automatically reflect your bundle identifier.
So you no need to replace bundle identifier each other App.